# CS-D808 and NEMA34 undervoltage

Tags: arduino, power, stepper-motor, driver, motordriver

I want to drive stepper motor with CS-D808 (30V-80V) but I don't have enough power, I have 24V. I couldn't move stepper motor. Is this because of power?
Here is my Arduino code:

```
#define dirPin 2
#define stepPin 3
#define enaPin 6
void setup(){
  pinMode(stepPin,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(dirPin,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(dirPin,HIGH);
  digitalWrite(enaPin,HIGH);
}
void loop(){
  digitalWrite(stepPin,HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(3000);   // i tried with 1500,5000,100,200 doesn't change
  digitalWrite(stepPin,LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(3000);
}
```

Is this code correct? I couldn't move stepper.

[image] I connected like this. CS-D808's +VCC to 24V's V+ and CS-D808 to 24V's V-.

[image]

I connected ENA to GND and ENA+ to pin 6.
Is it the power problem or is it the code? Or something else?

Comment: Why no trying your code first with little stepper motor ? CS-D808 (20 V- 80 V), so 24 V was ok. "Supply voltage of 20-80 VDC, maximum output current of 8.0A" in infos ???

Answer (score 2):

The datasheet really says that the *minimum* voltage is 30V; probably your stepper amplifier is in undervoltage lockout with only 24V.

Either change amplifier or power supply

Comment: Okay , thank you. The code is so simple, I though that might be problem. I will try to find power supply.

Answer (score 0):

1. If CS-D808 needs a voltage of (30V-80V) it's quite likely that the CS-D808 driver doesn't work properly.
2. Just having a power supply of 30 Volt is not enough.
   You need to verify that your power supply is able to deliver all the current that your motor needs.

Comment: Current is fine 6A but volt is not enough. I saw someone who is working with 24V the same driver and power supply. I am doing something wrong but I don't know.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. I didn't connected Encoders cable but Closed Loop motors encoders pins should be connected. I connected encoder cables and it is working now. Thank you everyone.